# Is it possible to set system environment variables from a node script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, environment-variables

I have an npm script like this that executes two node files:

package.json

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "my-target": "node setup.js && node run.js"
  }
}
```

Ideally, I can set environment variables in `setup.js` that can then be accessed in `run.js`.

setup.js

```js
process.env.HELLO_WORLD=1
```

run.js

```js
// Ideally prints `1`, instead prints undefined.
console.log(process.env.HELLO_WORLD);
```

Is something like this possible? Ideally the result of setting the environment variables in `setup.js` would be persistent, so that if I run

```
$ echo $HELLO_WORLD
```

from bash, that reference would still be there.

Comment: Why would you not just run `HELLO_WORLD=1 node setup.js && node run.js`?

Comment: because in reality the situation is more complex, I simplified it here to demonstrate what is needed. That is, I do not know what the value of the environment variable should be - it is dynamically determined by the setup script.

Comment: What you're attempting is impossible. Env vars are private to each process. When a process starts it inherits env vars from its parent. A process cannot modify the env of a different process.

Answer (score 1):

You can set env vars when you run the main program:

```
HELLO_WORLD=hello npm run my-target
```

*package.json:*

```
  "scripts": {
    "my-target": "node setup.js && node run.js"
  },
```

*setup.js:*

```
console.info('setup', process.env.HELLO_WORLD);
```

*run.js:*

```
console.info('run', process.env.HELLO_WORLD);
```

Output will be

```
setup hello
run hello
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. I do not actually know what the value of the environment variable should be - it is dynamically determined by the setup script.

Comment: This is not a really standard way of doing things, is there a reason the two scripts need to be separate like this?

Comment: Ideally, you would run `setup.js` which would determine your dynamic values/set env vars and you then `require/import` `run.js` and execute its functions as needed.